# Use Js imported by index.html using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I use ng-include to import sidebar and navbar in my webapp something like this

You are using an outdated</strong> browser. Please upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>

```
<div ng-include src="'navbar.html'"></div>
<div ng-include src="'sidebar.html'"></div>   
<div class="content">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="../static/bootadmin/js/theme.js"></script>
```

I want to use theme.js inside in both html file included.
What i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

The code is already correct. They can use it since theme.js is available globally.

EDIT 04/08/2014 : try to close the ng-include div not like this

```
<div ng-include... ></div>
```

but like this

```
<div ng-include... />
```

Comment: First check that html is correctly included. What does it change if you close the ng-include like this :<div ng-include src="'sidebar.html'"/> instead of <div ng-include src="'sidebar.html'"></div>    ?

Comment: when i use <div ng-include src="'sidebar.html'"/> it doesn't work

Comment: anyway i have to import the script into a sidebar.html and navbar.html, otherwise it doesn't work